# AWS, Amazon, Cognito and DynamoDB from NODEJS RESTAPI

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

we developing a REST API in NodeJS and use DynamoDB as database,

i pretend use Cognito for handle Auth multiple accounts, but in examples allways first get cognitoID and later use DynamoDB, its not posible send cognitoID to client and use this id or somthing similar like credential to access to DynamoDB whitout refind CognitoID??

```
FB.login(function (response) {
  if (response.authResponse) { // logged in
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:1699ebc0-7900-4099-b910-2df94f52a030',
      Logins: {
        'graph.facebook.com': response.authResponse.accessToken
      }
    });

    AWS.config.credentials.get(err,data){
      console.log('You are now logged in.');
      //Here i can use Dynamo without any problem, 
      //but i allways need save Facebook Token ID and get CognitoID
      //for ALL the connections
      //there is no way to save CognitoID and use this 
      //The ID of my users in Dynamo is CognitoID
      var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();
      db.listTables(function(err, data) {
         console.log(data.TableNames);
      });
    }
  } else {
    console.log('There was a problem logging you in.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey there, 
     Can I ask you few clarification questions?  Your goal is to authenticate the use of DynamoDB correct?  Are you asking if Cognito is the only way to do it NodeJS?  Or are you asking about passing a Cognito identity around as credentials?  Once you've authenticated "AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(...)" you are then just able to create a new DynamoDB object db = new AWS.DynamoDB().

Comment: hi, tnks, the second one, i want know if its posible use the CognitoID instead of facebook Toke, only use Facebook token for find or create the user in login time but not use for future calls to API

Comment: Yeah, that should be possible.  I'm trying to understand your use case though because Cognito can assign a set of IAM policies to that facebook token, which you can then use to authenticate the use of DynamoDB request.


For general information about using Cognito take a look at http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxBVEDL5Z8JKAC/Use-Amazon-Cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-AWS-authentication.


If you want to checkout Cognito in action in another application, check out https://github.com/awslabs/aws-dynamodb-mars-json-demo/blob/master/viewer/app/scripts/services/AWS.js.